# Liferay : How to Redirect to Public page using RequestDispatcher in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have defined a Page consisting of my six Portlets and configured that inside the `portal-ext.properties` file as my default Lnding page .

I have  a Custom Login Page for contacting to my Database , and once the user is Valid i am redirecting him to this page using  /user/test/home and also tried using `http://localhost:8086/user/test/home`

But this did not worked , i kept on getting

```java
public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
            throws PortletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        System.out.println("Inside the doView Method");
        PortletRequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
        if (this.name.isEmpty()) {
            dispatcher = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                    "/WEB-INF/jsp/AllInOne_view.jsp");
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("name", this.name);
            dispatcher = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                    "http://localhost:8086/user/test/home");
        }
        this.name = "";
        this.action = "";
        dispatcher.include(request, response);
    }


17:53:47,765 ERROR [render_portlet_jsp:154] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.ravi.learning.AllInOne.doView(AllInOne.java:57)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:93)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
```

The AllinOne.java is my Custom GenericPortlet class AllInOne.java:57 is

```java
    dispatcher.include(request, response);
```

**Updated Part Here**

This is the java Class

```java
package org.ravi.learning;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.GenericPortlet;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcher;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;

public class AllInOne extends GenericPortlet {
    String action = "";
    String name = "";

    public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
            throws PortletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Inside the Process Action Method new");

        this.action = request.getParameter("myAction");

        if (this.action.equals("formAction")) {
            this.name = request.getParameter("personName");

        }
        String urlpaths = "http://localhost:8086/user/test/home";
        response.sendRedirect(urlpaths);

    }

    public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
            throws PortletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");


    }

}
```

As a new user i cant post images , so please refer this external link for the image

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=a43nlv&s=5

Comment: Is getPortletContext() returning you an object? Just print and see what it returns

Comment: If i use an exist  JSP file getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher into it ,this works fine , but here i am using the default landing page , and its throwing me this error . So please tell me if using default landing page this way is correct or not ??

Comment: @user1318607 anything interesting in logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the jsr168 and jsr286 docs for PortletContext.getRequestDispatcher(),

> The pathname must begin with a slash ( / ) and is interpreted as
>   relative to the current context root.

So using `"http://localhost:8086/user/test/home"` as parameter is wrong.

What you probably want to do is a redirect. In portlet environment you can do it only in action request using `ActionResponse.sendRedirect(String)`

Comment: I will use ActionResponse , so here the String value should be /user/test/home ?? Is that correct ?

Comment: @user1318607 if you use actionResponse, you can use `http://localhost:8086/user/test/home`. The point is that you shouldn't (and can't) do redirects in `doView()`.